# Add Folder to Document Library

Tags: document-library, folder

I created a document library. I can add new document to the document library. But I want to add folder  my sharepoint site. How can I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: do you want to add a folder to the document library or to a site? what type of library is it?

Comment: Yes @ali.  I want to upload  folders instead of separately files to library or site. If I can upload folders to the document library, please say it's way  to me. But upload folders to document library isn't possible, how else can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most likely mean a folder inside a document library, because you cannot add a folder to a site that is available for end-users. In order to add a folder inside a document library, you need to open up the ability to add a folder to the document library.

- Go to the document library where you want to add a folder
- Go to the Library Settings
- Advanced Settings
- Make New Folder -> Set to Yes
- Now you will be able to see "New Folder" in the ribbon when you navigate to the document library

EDIT:

The best way to download a complete folder in my opinion would be to use Windows Explorer view. Just navigate to the library, and click on the Windows Explorer View, then copy the folder you want to download, and paste it on your computer.
[image]

Comment: I explained false. Actually, I want to download folders instead of separately files to library. How can I do this?@Mike

Comment: @zengel see my edit.

Comment: I tried this it's okey. But I want to install a new folder, such as installing new document. Is there any way for process? @Mike

Comment: Do you mean uploading a folder and it's contents? If so, then open up Windows Explorer and drag and drop the folder you want to upload to the Windows Explorer window. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean by "install a new folder"

Comment: thanks for help @Mike. I will upload with the Windows Explorer window.